# ASP.Net repeater web-part of a SharePoint list

Tags: web-part

This is driving me insane! Done this many times as a .Net developer but can't seem to get it working in a SharePoint webpart.

Page load code...

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Using site As New SPSite("http://cn-lap-hp-dev/")
        Using web As SPWeb = site.OpenWeb()
            Dim Imagelist As SPList = web.Lists("Home Page Carousel")
            rptCarousel.DataSource = Imagelist.Items.GetDataTable()
            rptCarousel.DataBind()
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

and the repeater code

```
Protected Sub rptCarousel_ItemDataBound(source As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles rptCarousel.ItemDataBound
    Dim litTitle As Literal
    Dim drv As DataRowView
    'Now add this record to the datarow
    drv = DirectCast(e.Item.DataItem, DataRowView)
    'Find and initialise our elements
    litTitle = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("litTitle"), Literal)
    'Now set our values
    litTitle.Text = drv("Title").ToString()

End Sub
```

Once i have deployed the webpart is running ok, its finding the SP list and it knows I have 3 items in my list (from the DIV's that are displaying by viewing source) but it will not display the data...is there any other way to debug this?

UPDATE:

WOW! Please ignore my stupidness! would help i had some content in my title eh?! The above works if anyone wants to use it.

However I need to display image but cant convert the Object to an image?

Comment: When you say you can't convert the object to an image what do you mean? Do you have a field in the list which holds an image URL?

Comment: Just sorted this, just forgot to convert to string...imgCarousel.ImageUrl = "Home%20Page%20Carousel/" & drv("LinkFilename").ToString()

Answer (score 1):

The above code works... But you need to make sure you have content in the list you're referencing! I had records but no Title for `litTitle.Text = drv("Title").ToString()`. Once I added some content to the Title it worked.

Also need to remember to `ToString()` everything that comes out.